# GNU Inline assembler — Syntax of assembly instructions?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, simd

In the following code, I can get the result of mm0 - mm1 in mm0 by PSUBSW instruction. When I compiled on Mac book air by gcc.

But, PSUBSW instruction is explained that we can get the result of mm1 - mm0 in mm1 in [Intel developer's manual](http://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf): *PSUBSW mm, mm/m64, Subtract signed packed words in mm/m64 from signed packed words in mm and saturate results.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  short int a[4] = {1111,1112,1113,1114};
  short int b[4] = {1111,2112,3113,4114};
  short int c[4];

  asm volatile (
  "movq (%1),%%mm0\n\t"
  "movq (%2),%%mm1\n\t"
  "psubsw %%mm1,%%mm0\n\t"
  "movq %%mm0,%0\n\t"
  "emms"
  : "=g"(c): "r"(&a),"r"(&b));

  printf("%d %d %d %d\n", c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3]);

  return 0;
}
```

What is this difference? Which is the src, mm0 or mm1? If this difference is Intel syntax and AT&T syntax.

Comment: Note that you don't have to write SIMD assembly to vectorize your code. If you write a loop `for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) { c[i] = a[i] - b[i]; }` then GCC can vectorize it for you. See more details in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409300/how-to-vectorize-with-gcc) thread and [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) GNU manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [GNU manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Basic-Assembler-Syntax.html) it states that *gcc is based not on the Intel assembly language, but rather on a language that descends from the AT&T Unix assembler*. There are two main camps on assembly syntax:

- Intel: `opcode dest, src`
- AT&T: `opcode src, dest`

In your example you're using AT&T syntax, the default. However, if you prefer to switch to Intel syntax, you can either compile with `-masm=intel` or use the following:

```
__asm__(".intel_syntax;" ...);
```

You can find more discussions of that topic in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397677/gcc-intel-syntax-inline-assembly) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax) Stackoverflow thread, or read more [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I understood that there is the difference that the order of the operand is reversed between AT&T syntax and Intel syntax in the instruction which has two operands.

Comment: It can be confusing at times :) What I do to find out which syntax is valid, I try to store an immediate into a register: `__asm__("mov $0, %eax");` and that will complain about the position of the immediate or the register naming. See [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s3) for more details.